# Javascript/HTML: Create and execute header script from string

Tags: javascript, html

I have a React app where I allow the user to specify `<script>` tags to be added as HTML headers. These are fetched after the document has loaded, and are stored as plain text properties (I can't just point `<script src="//some-location...` because it's a string, not a file). I have tried several things but nothing is working.

```
let json = loadDataFromServer();
console.log(json.headerHTML); // prints <script type="text/javascript">alert("Header script working");</script>

// This just appends it as a string to the header.
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].append(json.headerHTML);
```

[image]

```
// This appends the script tags properly, but doesn't run the script.
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + json.headerHTML;
```

[image]

It may be worth mentioning that this is part of a React app, but as far as I know `dangerouslySetInnerHTML()` cannot be used in the header, only body HTML.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, I am ignoring the obvious XSS problems this poses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`react-helmet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) may help achieve this. You can strip away the opening and closing `script` tag from the server's response and concatenate the header content as shown below.

```js
import {Helmet) from 'react-helmet'

...
return (
    <>
      <Helmet>
        {json.headerHTML ? (
          <script>
            {`
              ${json.headerHTML}
            `}
          </script>
        ) : null}
      </Helmet>
      ...
    </>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple. You need to create a DOM element and append it to the head.

```js
const element = document.createElement('script');
element.innerHTML += 'alert("hello");'
document.head.appendChild(element);
```